# Sending Post with JSON.stringify(obj) in body doesn't result in a string on API recieving side

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core, axios, rest

So I'm a bit stuck on this scenario.
I have a frontend sending the following request through Axios to my API:

```
const objectInBody = {
            Id,
            Input
        };
        
        const result: any = await axios.Post(`Order/Reservation`, JSON.stringify(objectInBody));
        return result.data;
```

And I have a RESTful .NET Core API running that recieves these requests.
Relevant routing logic:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Reservation([FromBody] string jsonObj)
        {

            Reservation reservation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reservation>(jsonObj);

            try
            {
                var result = await orderManager.Reserve(reservation);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The problem here is, my API blocks the request, because my API doesn't recognize the 'JSON.stringify(objectInBody)' as a string and will not run through the code.
When I pass other strings, the API accepts it without any problem and continues the logic. Which is weird to me because I thought the JSON.stringify results in a string type?

On console.log(JSON.stringify(objectInBody)); I get {Id:1, Input:1} without quotation marks.
But when I console.log(typeof(JSON.stringify(objectInBody))); it does say 'string' in my console.

I can also adjust the "expected" type in my API to JsonObject or something else, but this is a bad 'fix', since it seems to me Json.Stringify has to return a string and pass it without problems, like I said, not a JsonObject ofcourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your current code is not working, is because Axios don't send *Content-Type: application/json* automatically for string payloads. Hence, to make your current solution working, you'll have to do like this (please follow my recommendation at the end of this answer instead):

```
const result: any = await axios.post("Order/Reservation", JSON.stringify(objectInBody), {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}});
```

**Recommended solution**

You should change your controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Reservation([FromBody] Reservation reservation)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await orderManager.Reserve(reservation);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Then change your Axios call like this:

```
const result: any = await axios.post(`Order/Reservation`, objectInBody);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I do however wrote a private `SetHeaders()` function which succesfully executes before every HTTP request of any type, in which I use `axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8; application/json-patch+json';` When I inspect the error code I get as a response from the API, I do find the 'application/json' under Content-Type in the request-header section.

Comment: I am going to try your solution in a few hours when I get back on the project, but it seems weird to me to try and pass the entire object since, if i learned correctly, the entire reason `JSON.stringify` for javascript and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` exist would be for this scenario, no?

Comment: @Jasper: Using JSON and view model classes in controller signature is the mainstream way of doing things now. BR

Comment: I adjusted my code like you said, but I'm still getting [error 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). It's not the catch -> return BadRequest in my method itself, since I'm in debug mode working with breakpoints and it nevers enters the route. It appears my API doesn't understand it can 'fit' my JSON object into my Reservation class. The route otherwise works fine, when I remove the `[FromBody] Reservation reservation` in my controller and send an axios post with null as body, it does trigger the route and relevant breakpoints.

Comment: @Jasper: We'll need to clarify how your class `Reservation` looks like. In my tests, I use int for both Id and Input. What is your payload into the controller right now? If you press F12 in Chrome and make a request, you'll see the payload under Network.
Tests on my computer works with both {"Id": 1, "Input": 2} and {"id": 1, "input": 2} as payloads.

Comment: You're right, I tried @Serge 's earlier suggested fix sometime ago and forgot to alter my code. When I inspected my payload now I saw I had `{"Id": "Id", "Input": "Input"}` . After reversing changes today and going ahead with your earlier fix, the payload came through correctly and it routed correctly. Thank you. One small followup question, can I create another route with another type of json object that gets handled in the same controller by its own class? In other words, same HTTPPost route request with for example Order order in body and handle it in a different route?

Comment: ^I assume the controller will claim ambiguos routing and throw errors? Should I create seperate routes for each object or is it better to accept a base <Type> and filter in the route, depending on what object it recieves?

Comment: @Jasper: What I'm usually doing, is creating a controller for each type. E.g.: If you have a class User, then you will typically have a UserController with GET, POST, DELETE and PUT. Then you apply routing at controller level, and don't have to repeat routing for each method.  BR

Comment: I also try to do this, but `Reservation`s and `Order`s are part of my `Seller` object. Do you create a seperate controller for each type within a type aswell?

Comment: @Jasper: It depends. In many cases, I would have just a SellerController, and use PUT to add/remove/change Reservation and Order instances because I would then consider this as just a change to the main instance which is Seller. In that scenario you'll send in the Seller instance for all operations. BR

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that Reservation class is like this

```
public class Reservation 
{
  public string Id {get; set;}
   public string Input {get; set;}
}
```

Try this code

```
objectInBody = {
            Id:"id",
            Input: "input"
        };

 const result: any = await axios.Post('/Order/Reservation',
 { jsonObj:JSON.stringify(objectInBody)});
```

Comment: I make use of TSLint, which is TypeScipt's version of ESLint, which simplifies my code creating the object in javascript [Relevant doc](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props). I will try the other suggested solution first before altering my axios.Post method further, since this has worked for me in the past (with sending simpler types to be fair)